# python minidom - get data from parent nodes with the same name

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dom, minidom

I have an xml file with such structure:

```
<zone id=1 name=one>
  <subzone>
    <zone id=2 name=subone>
      ...
        <item>
        <item>
        ...

<zone id=1 name=two>
  <subzone>
    <zone id=2 name=subtwo>
      ...
        <item>
        <item>
        ...
```

I want to get a list of all items with an information about their parents. As example - `item, zone_id=1, zone_name=two, subzone_id=2, subzone_name=subtwo`.
Amount of `zone` nodes is differ for group of `items`. 
I can get the list of all zones:

```
def read_region(self, xml):
    doc = minidom.parse(xml)
    node = doc.getElementsByTagName("zone")
    for zone in node:
        print(zone.getAttribute("name"))
```

How can I get data from the specific node if there are a lot of nodes with the same nodename? Or is it possible to get an information about all parent nodes of an element?

Answer (score 2):

You ask two questions:

1. How do get a specific element from among many elements of the same name?
2. How do I get all the parent elements of a given element?

   1. To get a specific element, you have to identify what *is* different about that element. It could be a relationship to another element that is uniquely identifiable.
   2. You can get all the parents of an element by repeatedly calling `node.getparent()` as below. See http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html .

      ```
      def get_parents(element):
          ancestors = []
          parent = element.getparent()
          while parent != None:
              ancestors.append(parent)
              parent = parent.getparent()
          return ancestors
      ```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I am using minidom, not lxml. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
def read_region(self, xml):
        doc = minidom.parse(xml)
        node = doc.getElementsByTagName("Zone")
        data_array = []
        for zone in node:
            zone_child = zone.getElementsByTagName("Zone")
            if len(zone_child)==0:
                print(zone.getAttribute("name"))
                subzone_parent = zone.parentNode
                zone_parent = subzone_parent.parentNode
                print(zone_parent.getAttribute("name"))

                subzone_parent_parent = zone_parent.parentNode
                zone_parent_parent = subzone_parent_parent.parentNode
                print(zone_parent_parent.getAttribute("name"))

                subzone_top = zone_parent_parent.parentNode
                zone_top = subzone_top.parentNode
                try:
                    print(zone_top.getAttribute("name"))
                except Exception,e:
                    print("DEBUG")
```

I check that there are no childs in Zone node and get each parent for that node.